# Nested loop in imacros

Tags: javascript, loops, nested, imacros

I want to use nested loop in iMacros.

```
macro =  "CODE:";
macro += "URL GOTO=https://www.pleasehelp.org/search.php?type=0&sort=pop&page={{n}} " + "\n";
macro += "TAG POS={{i}} TYPE=B ATTR=TEXT:*" + "\n";
macro += "TAG POS=1 TYPE=A ATTR=TXT:Send" + "\n"; 

for (var n = 5; n < 700; n++) {

    for (var i=6;i<30;i++)
    {
        iimSet("i",i)
        iimPlay(macro)
        iimSet("n",n)
        n = n + 1
    }

}
```

I want first loop to be executed once the second loop completed. But both loops are executing together. Please suggest how can we achieve this. ?

Comment: What do you mean by first and second loop? Is the first the inner or the outer loop?

Comment: First the outer loop and second is the inner loop.

Comment: You do not have any statements located in the outer loop, so what exactly do you want to do?

Comment: macro += "URL GOTO=https://www.pleasehelp.org/search.php?type=0&sort=pop&page={{n}} " + "\n";. value in url "n"  to be changed by outer loop.